# Understanding data length

Tags: mariadb

How does the `LENGTH()` query relate to actual size of the data?
I notice that when I save this data to a text file, it's approximately 2% larger than the `LENGTH()` query.  What is happening here?  Here's an example on linux using MariaDB 10.3.16.
`du` and `ls` both agree`.

```
$ mysql -ufugu -p projects -e "SELECT ID, LENGTH(CutXML) as length FROM renders ORDER BY length DESC LIMIT 1"
Enter password: 
+-----+---------+
| ID  | length  |
+-----+---------+
| 350 | 3431670 |
+-----+---------+
$ mysql -ufugu -p projects -e "SELECT CutXML FROM renders WHERE ID=350" > cut.xml
Enter password: 
$ ls -al cut.xml 
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 3512937 Aug 20 14:23 cut.xml
$ du -b cut.xml 
3512937 cut.xml
```

Comment: Likely because there is a data compression algorithm in the database engine that stores XML more efficiently than a text file.

Comment: almost all compresions would work more efficient than that. It is more likely that the storage engine of the operating system uses more space to store the data

Comment: Yes, XML typically shrinks by 3x (not 2%).  MariaDB does not compress without asking for it.

Answer (score 0):

Only 2%?

Check the line terminators.  For the column, do something like `SELECT HEX(LEFT(COL(100)))`.  For the file, do something like `od` or `hd` or take the cat to the vet (`cat -vet`).

A Rule of Thumb is that an average line of "text" is 30 characters, which would lead to about a 3% difference.  XML is rather verbose, and your data may be averaging 50 bytes per "line".